# Create shaded rectangle with geom_mark_rect using 4 coordinates as inputs?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

How can a [ggforce rectangle](https://rdrr.io/cran/ggforce/man/geom_mark_rect.html) be used to easily rectangular mark an area defined by four sets of xy coordinates?

#### Minimal example

I would have expected this to work (or at least produce something close)

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggforce)
set.seed(123)
data.frame(x = runif(20)* 1000, y = runif(20)* 1000) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_mark_rect(x = c(500, 750, 500, 750), y = c(250, 250, 500, 500))
```

but it produces this, where the placement is off:

[image]

A rectangle in this position is the goal (the rectangle below isn't shaded, but ggforce should shade it automatically):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't put your x and y points in an aesthetics call (`aes`). Actually, since `geom_mark_rect` will inherit its `aes` from the call to `ggplot`, you can just supply the x and y co-ordinates as a data frame. Here's a reproducible example:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggforce)

set.seed(123)
data.frame(x = runif(20) * 1000, y = runif(20) * 1000) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_mark_rect(data = data.frame(x = c(500, 750, 500, 750), 
                                   y = c(250, 250, 500, 500)), fill = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: When I try this on my actual plot, it says `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'Rating' not found`.  If I set `inheret.aes = FALSE`, I see: `Error: geom_mark_rect requires the following missing aesthetics: x and y`. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably worth noting that the plot generates perfectly before I try to add the rectangle.

Comment: @dss try `geom_mark_rect(data = data.frame(x = c(500, 750, 500, 750), y = c(250, 250, 500, 500)), inherit.aes = FALSE, aes(x=x, y=y))`

Comment: Sorry for all the questions. Do you know how to remove the thin black border around the edge? I've tried including `linetype = "none"` in the `aes()`, also `label.margin` to each of `0`, `NULL`, and `element_blank()`, but I can't get rid of it

Comment: `colour="none"` or `colour-NULL`?